# EditText doesn't update its text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, tostring

**EDIT2:**
Using

```java
fragTransaction.add(fragment, tag);
```

instead of

```java
fragTransaction.add(id, fragment);
```

OR

Removing all Fragments code in MainActivity  makes the app works again, for some odd reason.

---

Getting the text via `.getText().toString()` returns null/empty when button is pressed.

Tried to manually `.setText("something")`, it works when `.getText().toString()` is called but,

when the text is modified, calling `.getText().toString()` will still return "something".

**MainActivity.java**

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment loginFrag = new LoginFragment();

        fragTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fragTransaction.add(R.id.mainFrag, loginFrag);
        fragTransaction.commit();
    }
```

**LoginFragment.java**

```java
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment{
    EditText fieldID;
    EditText fieldPassword;
    Button logButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_menu, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        view = v;

        fieldID = v.findViewById(R.id.fieldID);
        fieldPassword = v.findViewById(R.id.fieldPassword);
        logButton = v.findViewById(R.id.button_login);



        logButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn(fieldID.getText().toString(), fieldPassword.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void signIn(String email, String password) {
        System.out.println("Email: " + email);
        System.out.println("Pass: " + password);

        if(!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                Log.d("Auth", "signInWithEmail:success");
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                //updateUI(user);

                                view.findViewById(R.id.logoMain).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                Log.w("Auth", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                //updateUI(null);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presenter.Activity.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFrag"
        android:name="com.raze.mfa.presenter.Fragment.LoginFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Fragment Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logoMain"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bak"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/bak" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconlock"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fieldPassword"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.523"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iconuser"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/lockicon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconuser"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fieldID"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.522"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/usericon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/loginText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fieldPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.188" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fieldPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fieldID" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fieldID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoMain"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fieldID"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logoimg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_login"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Unrelated:
I've Googled mostly everything but it seems that I haven't understand the basics of using Fragments, Activites, context, Views, and etc.

Comment: There's no indication of a bug there. Only possible reason I see is that you reference wrong views. Mind adding your fragment layout file?

Comment: @Niklas I've added the layout file, hopefully you'll find the bug, thanks!

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is here. Can you describe step-by-step what the user does in the app and what happens differently than what you want? Post screenshots to illustrate.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Whenever I try to log in, entering my ID (email ) and password, pressing the login button afterwards, the received string ( from EditText's gettext() ) is empty.
Say for instance, I enter in "abc@cd.e" in fieldID box and "123" in pass box, and attempt to get the text, the app receives empty string.

Pretty much, the EditText doesnt listen to changes made to the text.

Comment: Really, your code should run just fine, I don't see any problem with it...

Comment: Could you post all of your main activity and fragment code?

Comment: That's honestly all of it @PFuster, other than imports and package.

Comment: Check my answer I found out why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I see, you are using a `<fragment/>` tag already in your MainActivity layout, and then you add with the `FragmentTransaction` a fragment to it.

The transaction is for `FrameLayout` containers that are empty and take a fragment. When you add the fragment statically through the `<fragment/>` tag the fragment is already loaded into the screen.

Something weird was happening when you added a new fragment to a fragment tag, maybe it duplicated the fragment and it was reading the one that is behind the actual fragment and it wasn't getting the input from the user.

Read here for the proper use of FragmentTransaction: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui

Taken from the docs above, see how they use a `FrameLayout` as the container.

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}
}
```